# Remote screen command through ssh, unable to see active sessions

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen, session

Let's say i'm running a comand using:
`ssh user@ip screen -dm cat file`
or a command like:
`ssh user@ip screen -dm -S sessionname cat file`
Why, in both cases I can't see active screen sessions and so, the output of `cat` command?
I'm doing: `screen -ls` or `screen -x sessionname` but I don't see active sessions.

Comment: Did you try "ssh user@ip screen -ls" ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, it print: No Sockets found.  
What happen is that execution terminate, and so, session ends.
I found similar question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47271/prevent-gnu-screen-from-terminating-session-once-executed-script-ends 
But even following these suggestions, I'm still not able to perform for example cat filename keeping program output, in the session, instead, using top; exec bash (as suggested in posted link), it keeps running.

Comment: Ah yes, when a session terminates it is quite often no longer active.

Comment: But if I run:  
`ssh user@ip screen -dmS session_name sh -c 'cat filename; exec bash'`  
Doesn't work, instead, for example, the following works:  
`ssh user@ip screen -dmS session_name sh -c 'top; exec bash'`  
Why?

Comment: If I run in my local machine:  
`screen -dm -S sessionname sh -c 'cat filename; exec bash'`
sessionname keeps running, instead, using in through ssh:  
`ssh username@ip screen -dm -S sessionname sh -c 'cat filename; exec bash'`  
Leaves me a blank screen session.